# Element-wise dictionary creation from two pandas series (columns of csv as DataFrame)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm looking to do a row by row dictionary mapping of two columns of a headered multi-column csv read in to a `pandas DataFrame` via `read_csv()`. In other words, for each row, make the value in column X the key, and the corresponding value in column Y the value.

With many operations in `pandas` being element-wise, I surmised that I could possibly achieve this with the following one-liner:

```
{df['X'] : df['Y']}
```

Alas, no such luck.

Does `pandas` expose its own way of doing this? I'll also be looking to something similar with a .xls and a .xlsx.

- Python: 2.7.11
- Pandas: 0.18

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426292/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-a-dictionary-of-two-pandas-dataframe-co ?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
dict(zip(df['X'].values, df['Y'].values))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the values in `X` are not unique, then you will be overwriting your keys.

Assuming that they are unique, then you can use a dictionary comprehension with `zip`.

```
{key: val for key, val in zip(df.X, df.Y)}
```