# How do I store the first use date in a dictionary using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset of userids and the all the times they use a particular pass. I need to find out how many days since each of them first used the pass. I was thinking of running through the dataset and store the first use in a dictionary and minus it off today's date. I cant seem to get it to work.

Userid  Start use   Day
1712    2019-01-04  Friday
1712    2019-01-05  Saturday
9050    2019-01-04  Friday
9050    2019-01-04  Friday
9050    2019-01-06  Sunday
9409    2019-01-05  Saturday
9683    2019-05-20  Monday
8800    2019-05-17  Friday
8800    2019-05-17  Friday

This is the part of the dataset. Date format is Y-m-d

```
usedict={}  
keys = df.user_id  
values = df.start_date  
for i in keys:  
    if (usedict[i] == keys):  
      continue   
else:  
    usedict[i] = values[i]  
prints(usedict)
```

user_id use_count days_used Ave Daily Trips register_date   days_since_reg
12  42  23  1.826087    NaT NaT
17  28  13  2.153846    NaT NaT
114 54  24  2.250000    2019-02-04  107 days
169 31  17  1.823529    NaT NaT
1414    49  20  2.450000    NaT NaT
1712    76  34  2.235294    NaT NaT
2388    24  12  2.000000    NaT NaT
6150    10  5   2.000000    2019-02-05  106 days

Comment: find the min start for each id?

Comment: 1. Seems there're some indentation problem in your else branch.

2. you can assign value(date time) to each key(userid) in your `usedict` by adding a condition check if's the earliest date just like what bubble sorting does

Answer (score 0):

I am only looking at two columns but you could find the min for each id with groupby and then use apply to get difference (I have done difference in days)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

user_id = [1712, 1712, 9050, 9050, 9050, 9409, 9683, 8800, 8800]
start = ['2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-05', '2019-05-20', '2019-05-17', '2019-05-17']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(user_id, start)), columns = ['UserId', 'Start'])
df['Start']= pd.to_datetime(df['Start']) 
df = df.groupby('UserId')['Start'].agg([pd.np.min])
now = datetime.datetime.now()
df['days'] = df['amin'].apply(lambda x: (now - x).days)
a_dict = pd.Series(df.days.values,index = df.index).to_dict()
print(a_dict)
```

**References:**

to_dict() method taken from [@jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426500/6241235)

---

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with the following. I have used only 2 user ids from the example given by you, but the same will apply to all.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Userid':'1712','use_date':'2019-01-04'},
                    {'Userid':'1712','use_date':'2019-01-05'},
                    {'Userid':'9050','use_date':'2019-01-04'},
                    {'Userid':'9050','use_date':'2019-01-04'},
                    {'Userid':'9050','use_date':'2019-01-06'}])

df.use_date = pd.to_datetime(df.use_date).dt.date
group_df = df.sort_values(by='use_date').groupby('Userid', as_index=False).agg({'use_date':'first'}).rename(columns={'use_date':'first_use_date'})

group_df['diff_from_today'] = datetime.datetime.today().date() - group_df.first_use_date
```

The output is:

```
print(group_df)
  Userid first_use_date diff_from_today
0   1712     2019-01-04        139 days
1   9050     2019-01-04        139 days
```

Check [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for more details.