# Create a dict using two columns from dataframe with duplicates in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dict from 2 columns of a dataframe.

Let's say they look like this:

```
A         B
car1     brand1
car2     brand2
car3     brand1
car4     brand3
car5     brand2
```

output:

```
{'brand1': ['car1', 'car3'], 'brand2': ['car2', 'car5'], 'brand3': 'car4'}
```

There is to_dict method, however when i try to use it, i can't get it to add values to keys, instead it only maps 1 value to 1 key.

I know I can for loop column A, check value in column B with iloc and then make if else to either create a new key or add a value to existing key, but I am looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: what's an "elegant solution" when a solution isn't possible? Dicts must have unique keys. Maybe use dicts with lists as value.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh the keys are unique. Keys are brands, and there can be mutliple values (cars) per key. In column B when for example brand1 appears for a second time, we just add car3 to an already existing key.

Comment: Your output isn't valid python

Comment: fixed to valid python so it's clear for everyone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Borrowing from [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby) you can aggregate to list with a groupby, then use `to_dict()`

```
df.groupby('B')['A'].apply(list).to_dict()
{'brand1': ['car1', 'car3'], 'brand2': ['car2', 'car5'], 'brand3': ['car4']}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was getting wrong the apply(list) part.