# How to generate array of key:values from merging columns

Tags: python, pandas

In need to create a new column which will merge all month columns and display their values as an array of key-values pairs.

I was already able to merge the columns:

```
df["Consumo"] = df.iloc[:,[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]].values.tolist()
```

I'm just not sure how I'm supposed to map through the values first in order to arrange the key-values array.

Sure, I could iterate over each column and then iterate over each row, but it would take take me somehow to keep the values and then push into an array of arrays...
I thought about something like that, I could keep this huge array of arrays and then push it into the df["Consumo"], would that work?

Input Data:

```
Cód. Perfil Sigla Nome Empresarial ... 2020-10-01 00:00:00 2020-11-01 00:00:00 2020-12-01 00:00:00 ...
3    RGE SUL RGE SUL DISTRIBUIDORA DE ENERGIA S.A. ... 230357.542859 284340.749249 337758.293447 ...
```

Expected Output:

```
Cód. Perfil Sigla Nome Empresarial Patamar Consumo
3    RGE SUL RGE SUL DISTRIBUIDORA DE ENERGIA S.A.LEVE  [2020-10-01 00:00:00: 375637.681828, 2020-10-01 00:00:00: 350523.989792, 2020-10-01 00:00:00: 314549.742607, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), [**`groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), and [**`apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) a dict mapping.

Using a simplified example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Perfil': ['SUL', 'ABC'], 'Sigla': ['RGE', 'XYZ'], 'Name': ['SUL', 'ABC'],
    '2020-10-01 00:00:00': [230357.542859, 372356.997901],
    '2020-11-01 00:00:00': [284340.749249, 455408.113981],
    '2020-12-01 00:00:00': [337758.293447, 698728.068559],
})
```

|  | Perfil | Sigla | Name | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SUL | RGE | SUL | 230357.542859 | 284340.749249 | 337758.293447 |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | ABC | 372356.997901 | 455408.113981 | 698728.068559 |

First [**`melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) by the non-month columns:

```py
non_months = df.columns[0:3] # change as needed for the real data
df = df.melt(id_vars=non_months)
```

|  | Perfil | Sigla | Name | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SUL | RGE | SUL | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 230357.542859 |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | ABC | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 372356.997901 |
| 2 | SUL | RGE | SUL | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 284340.749249 |
| 3 | ABC | XYZ | ABC | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 455408.113981 |
| 4 | SUL | RGE | SUL | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 337758.293447 |
| 5 | ABC | XYZ | ABC | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 698728.068559 |

Then [**`groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the non-month columns and [**`apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) a dict mapping:

```py
df = (df.groupby(list(non_months))
        .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.variable, x.value)))
        .to_frame(name='Consumo'))
```

| Perfil | Sigla | Name | Consumo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | ABC | {'2020-10-01 00:00:00': 372356.997901, '2020-1... |
| SUL | RGE | SUL | {'2020-10-01 00:00:00': 230357.542859, '2020-1... |

---

Note: If you want slightly better performance, you can [replace the dict-zip lambda with `Series.to_dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426500/13138364):

```
lambda x: pd.Series(x.value.values, index=x.variable).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["Consumo"] = df.iloc[:,[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]].to_dict("records")
df["Consumo"] = df["Consumo"].map(str).str[1:-1]
```

`to_dict` is the key here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html (you just need to choose proper orientation of output `dict`).

Then second line is just to drop sorrounding `dict` brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more elegant way of doing it, but well, this one worked for me:

```
for col in df.iloc[:,[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]]:
    i = df.columns.get_loc(col)
    for j, row_value in df[col].iteritems():
        if i == 4:
            series.append([{col:row_value}])
        else:
            series[j].append({col:row_value})

df["Consumo"] = series
```